# How to copy Google Analytics data into SQL Server tables

Tags: google-analytics

I just started working on Google Analytics stuff and I'm pretty new to this. I am now granted access to GA account of my Organization's marketing Website for several European countries(single login).

My requirement is to copy different European countries GA data into a single table structure in SQL server. Wondering if anyone of you have done this before? Any suggestions are highly appreciated.

Comment: This is a bit broad, since answer range from "export CSV data and do a load statement" to "use the API" and we do neither know your programming environment nor your SQL dialect. The expected format for questions on SO (as per http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) is specific code problems rather than general "how to" questions. So can you narrow it down a bit ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a number of ways of doing this.   Google Analytics does have the ability to export data as CSV but its going to be hard to match up the data properly.

If you are up for a bit of programming.  start with the [Google Analytics API](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/) it will allow you to extract data from Google analytics and insert it where you like.   You can use any programming language that is capable of preforming a HTTP Post and HTTP Get. However i recommend looking into one of Googles client libraries.

If you have the ability to use SSIS to you can use [Targit Google Analytics SSIS](http://www.daimto.com/targit-google-analytics-ssis/) its a custom connection manager and data reader for extracting data from Google analytics it is free to use.   *Note: Full disclosure I am the lead developer on that project.*